# CSS alignment issue with image and text

Tags: css, image, layout, alignment

I'm having problems getting my icon to line up with the text, tried every combination i can think of, still aligned at top

http://jsfiddle.net/gkC32/1/

Any help would be great?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `vertical-align` property on the `img` element?

```
.bluebutton img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Alternatively, since you're using the image purely as decoration, you might want to use `background-image` to set the icon instead:

```
.bluebutton {
    background: #336699 url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/16x16_0460/group_add.png') no-repeat 10px center;
    padding: 3px 10px 4px 28px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gkC32/8/

Comment: yep, thats all it was, didnt think about styling just the image, what a pain, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the image that's throwing it out I think. Adding something like:

```
.bluebutton img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Should do the trick. If you arranged it differently as well, you could improve the alignment slightly further. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gkC32/32/